# Bash: creating wordlists

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, shell, regex

I'm trying to output every possible combination between {a..z} and {0..9}; this output without using tools like `crunch`:

```
$ head wordlist.txt

a
b
c
1
2
3
aa
ab
ac
a1

$ tail wordlist.txt

333332c
3333321
3333322
3333323
333333a
333333b
333333c
3333331
3333332
3333333
```

Can we do with regex? I tried combinations of things like:

```
for i in $(<magic here>); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

But that got me nowhere...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this gets huge rather quickly: all permutations of 6 characters along 36 (lowercase+digits): 36**6=2176782336 which is 2176 millions. Multiply by the size (6) and you need 12 Gigabytes. So you cannot really generate the whole list. If you can't use "generators" like you have in Python (that generate loop values as you need them), you need to do something like:

```
for t1 in $chars; do 
    for t2 in $chars; do 
        for t3 in $chars; do 
            for t4 in $chars; do 
                for t5 in $chars; do
                    echo $t1$t2$t3$t4$t5
                done
            done
        done
    done
done
```

If you need the shorter strings:

```
#! /bin/bash

chars=('' a b c)

for t1 in "${chars[@]}"; do 
    for t2 in "${chars[@]}"; do 
        for t3 in "${chars[@]}"; do
            echo $t1$t2$t3
        done
    done
done
```

According to my system monitor, the code doesn't significantly increase the memory used by the bash process (around 2MB all along while it produces 29.5MB of output according to `pv -b`). For comparison, this equivalent code (with slightly shorter lists):

```
for t in {a..t}{a..t}{a..t}{a..t}{a..t} ; do 
    echo $t
done
```

Takes 600MB of RAM to run.

Choose wisely :)

Comment: xenoid - did you downvote me ?   Also, your answer does not address cases of "a", "aa" etc

Comment: No I didn't downvote anything... Updated the solution to output the shorter strings...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how precise you need to do it, and the tolerable overhead, you may be able to get away with something like

```
echo {\ ,{A..Z},{a..z},{0..9}}{\ ,{A..Z},{a..z},{0..9}}{\ ,{A..Z},{a..z},{0..9}}
```

Where you would repeat the **{\ ,{A..Z},{a..z},{0..9}}** bit for each set - ie if you wanted each word to be a maximum of 10 characters, you would repeat it 10 times.

There is a deficiency in the code in that (because it does not recognise "no character" at the beginning, I've used " " as a placeholder.  This will create duplicates - ie "99 " and " 99".    You could possiby get rid of these by pushing it through a sort|uniq filter (and maybe using tr as well), but depending on your application and the size of the final output, you might struggle with the time it will take to create the list.

To create a list which will output all permutations without duplicates, but in a different order to your original input you could use

```
for each in {\ ,{A..Z},{a..z},{0..9}}{\ ,{A..Z},{a..z},{0..9}}{\ ,{A..Z},{a..z},{0..9}} ; do  echo $each; done | tr -d " " | sort -u
```